# oracle: how to select for update in pagination?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pagination, locking

Lock limited results of a query in case of pagination:

```
select * from Employee order by id asc
```

as

```
select * from (select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from 
(select * from Employee order by id asc) a 
where ROWNUM <= 10) where rnum  >= 6 for update
```

Error:

```
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

How to select rows FOR UPDATE in pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ROWID with FOR UPDATE clause in this case.

Try:

```
select * from
Employee
where rowid in
(
  select r from
    (select rowid r from
     Employee
     order by id asc
    ) a
    where rownum <= 10
) for update;
```

Comment: where to put pagination offset?  does this approach work for more generic case: e.g., From clause that has joins and selection from multiple tables? Thanks.

Comment: e.g.,  select e.*, r.* from Employee e inner join Employer r on (e.employer_id=r.id) where r.id=100 order by e.id asc